# Javascript, var name = 1, "typeof name" gives "string"?

Tags: javascript, var, typeof

I found this weird problem, when I write Javascript code like below:

```
var name = 1;
alert(typeof name); // this will alert "string"
var b = 1;
alert(typeof b); // this will alert "number"
```

I got "string" for "typeof name", but got "number" for "typeof b", however, I think they both should be "number"

And this code won't run either:

```
var name = 1;
if (name === 1) {
    alert("ok")
}
```

It won't alert out, since name's type is "string" !

I tested above code in Chrome and Safari, they both give the same result, so why "typeof name" is "string" in this case? why the variable name "name" is so special?

Comment: but it works like charm(properly) -> http://jsfiddle.net/s2tnns49/1/

Comment: In browsers, the [global `name`, or `window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), is already defined to always be a string.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com not really... see below

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Note that JSFiddle's `onLoad` option wraps the code in an event handler, adding an additional scope for local variables that won't clash with predefined globals.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com your example is working because it is in a window onload handler so it is not a global variable  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s2tnns49/2/

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Thanks, try put your code inside a <script> tag inside html page, or test it in Chrome / Safari dev console, it will alert "string"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a behavior of the browser where some properties of window object like name and status will take only string values, if you assign any other type of values then the toString() value of that object is assigned to it

```
var name = 1;
console.log(typeof name); // this will alert "string"

var status  = 1;
console.log(status, typeof status); //gives '1` and string

var status = {};
console.log(status, typeof status);//gives value of status as [object Object] since that is the toString() implementation of object

var b = 1;
console.log(typeof b); //
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/057jfrr7/)

---

This behavior is not applicable if you use local variables... ie variables in a function

```
function test(){
    var name = 1;
    console.log(typeof name); // this will alert "string"

    var status  = 1;
    console.log(status, typeof status); //gives '1` and string

    var status = {};
    console.log(status, typeof status);//gives value of status as [object Object] since that is the toString() implementation of object

    var b = 1;
    console.log(typeof b); //

}

test()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/057jfrr7/3/)

Comment: ok so if you use name1 instead of name , it gives Number correct ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com yes it does

Comment: @ArunPJohny Interesting, thank you very much, I am wondering that besides "name" and "status", is there any other variable has such behavior? or is there an official/unofficial document for those "built-in & special" variables?

Comment: @BoTinker http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wt1h41r3/3/

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that there is a property under `window` named `name` (`window.name`) and it is already defined as a string.

When you declare a variable with no scope, it's scoped under `window`.

Check more about [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).