# Why variable "name" is typed as string?

Tags: javascript

I'm not new in javascript but i don't understand this behaviour at all.

Why a variable named "name" is typed as string only ? Its a new ES6 feature ??

```js
var name = 56;
console.log(name, typeof name);
name = function(){console.log("ok");}
console.log(name, typeof name);
```

Comment: `name` is an property on `window` object, don't use that  as variable in global scope, use any other name you will not see this behaviour

Comment: because window.name is a global variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the variable "name" doesn't work with a JS object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object) and [Javascript, var name = 1, “typeof name” gives “string”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360290) and [var name produces strange result in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945498)

Comment: i understand it's a global variable, i just didn't understand why all values are converted to string, according to developer.mozilla its not a bug its a feature. I didn't know this at all, is it possible to force variable type like this ? or this is defined in the core engine ?

Comment: @Daphoque you will find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21396286/9624435) helpful

Comment: @Daphoque [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name#Notes) clearly states that it converts all the value to their string representation using `toString`

Comment: Yeah i see that :) When you first see this and you're not aware of it it's quite strange. Thanks everyone i will sleep less stupid tonight :D

Comment: @Daphoque this will help you more [Browsing context name](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#browsing-context-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` it's a property of global object `window` and you cant replace it.

But you can `delete` and then define again

```
delete window.name;

window.name = ()=>{console.log('ok')}
```

But i don't recommend change global properties.

In node environment all work good:

[image]

Comment: Sure, you can replace it ```delete window.name;
var name = function(){};
console.log(typeof name);```

Comment: we can replace it, we cannot just change the type

Comment: This is a helpful link to understand why `window.name` is always a string [Browsing context name](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#browsing-context-name)