# Javascript - retrieving object property using bracket property and getting undefined

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript object creation using the constructor method and I am unable to understand one small behavior of the constructor in one of the examples.

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
            function User(name,age){
                this.name=name;
                this.age=age;
            }
            var user = new User('Daniel',45);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user[name];     // Return undefined
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user["name"];   // Return Daniel.
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user[age];      // Retutn nothing. Blank
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user["age"];    // Return 45
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I read that object properties can be accessed with either Dot operator or Bracket operator. And here bracket operator seems to be working fine. Now I am unable to understand two things here.

1. `user[name]` is returning `undefined`. Why `undefined`?
2. `user[age]` is returning nothing. Why is it not returning `undefined` like in previous case?
   What am I missing here?

Comment: The idea of the bracket notation is, that there is a string, or any expression which can be evaluated to a string, in the brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
user[name]
```

This looks up the property stored in the `name` variable. For example, if you had

```
const name = 'foo';
const result = user[name];
```

This is equivalent to:

```
const result = user.foo;
```

because `foo` is stored in the `name` variable.

The same thing is happening with `age`.

In contrast, when you use quotes, the interpreter doesn't look up a variable name, it just uses the plain string:

```
const result = user['foo']
```

is equivalent to

```
const result = user.foo;
```

But, keep in mind: best to avoid using the `name` variable, because on the top level, it exists as [`window.name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360290/javascript-var-name-1-typeof-name-gives-string) which must always be a string, which can result in weird bugs if you're not expecting it.

Comment: Hmm... "This looks up the property stored in the name variable" makes sense to me now and when I am trying to access it, it's giving me undefined. Then why don't I get undefined for age as well? why it is blank when I am doing user[age];?

Comment: You don't have a variable named `age`, so it throws an error: `age is not defined`. In contrast, the `name` variable exists because of `window.name` (but it's usually the empty string) - so, in that case, it won't throw an error, but still won't give you what you're expecting.

Comment: Wow... Now i understand it. by the way what is this window.name? Is it inbuilt? Please tell me a little bit more about it.

Comment: You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you write `user[name]` (assuming the name is `Daniel`) you are essentially trying to access the value at the key of `Daniel` which is a valid key. If this case `Daniel` would be the value at the key of `name`. Try doing this.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user.name;     // Return undefined
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user["name"];   // Return Daniel.
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user.age;      // Return nothing. Blank
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user["age"];
```

Use the `.name` rather than `[name]` to get the value at the key of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

when you do  `user[name]` what you really are doing is passing a variable called name and since you don't have a variable called name declared you will get undefined.

when you are doing `user["name"]` what you are doing is telling that you want to access the key `name` inside of your object.

you can also do

`user.name`

it will return the same thing as `user['name']`

Comment: why this same behavior is not happening with age retrieval as well? I have not defined age var also.

Comment: the same thing applies to the age and any key you have in your object. The key's (name and age) are pointers inside of your object so that you can find you value by key instead of like an array where you can find you value by index

Answer (score -2):

You did not defined any name and age variables, so `user[name]` and `user[age]` will be undefined.

You need defined variable `var name = "name"` and use `user[name]` as below

```html
<html>
<body>
<h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
            function User(name,age){
                this.name=name;
                this.age=age;
            }
            var user = new User('Daniel',45);
            var name = "name";
            var age = "age";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user[name];     // Return undefined
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user["name"];   // Return Daniel.
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user[age];      // Retutn nothing. Blank
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = user["age"];    // Return 45
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I see that part is working. see below to that code, I have posted my query. Could you help me resolve those questions?

Comment: You can set variable with name = "name" or use direct user["name"]