# Why type of variable does not change in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider this JS code:

```js
var name = "jack";

console.log(typeof name);
//'string'

name = {age: 40};

console.log(typeof name);
//'string'
```

Why does changing the variable does not change its type?

Comment: Try naming the variable something other than `name`.

Comment: Related: [Why is the variable `closed` being logged as `false`, if I define it globally as `0`?](/a/51062916/4642212).

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360290/javascript-var-name-1-typeof-name-gives-string) conversation.